# Makefile : extraneous implicit object file

Tags: makefile

Consider the following simple Makefile rule

```
target : objDir/target.o
    (...recipe...)

objDir/target.o : target.c
    (...recipe...)
```

I want to generate `target.o` into a dedicated directory, on purpose.

But this recipe will fail. Because when invoking `make target`, it will try to generate both `objDir/target.o` AND `target.o`, and then at link stage, it will fail due to duplicate symbols.

It appears that `target.o` is an implicit dependency, even though it was never specified in the list, and the list is non-empty. `target.o` can then be satisfied because `target.c` exists in the same directory.

So I can think of multiple complex ways to get rid of the issue, from renaming the source file, or changing the name of the target, to delegating to some sub-Makefile started from another directory, but none of them feels satisfying.

The question is :
is there a way to tell `make` to NOT assume a `target.o` dependency for `target` target ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. What version of Make are you using?

Comment: Your statement _Because when invoking `make target`, it will try to generate both `objDir/target.o` AND `target.o`_ is definitely not true, given the makefile you've provided here.  So if that's what you're seeing, you have left out some critical aspect of your makefile and it's that aspect which is causing your problems.  Please try to create a minimal reproducing example and post it here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. They are useful, as they imply that this should not happen. I need to come back to the `Makefile` then. As can be guessed, this is merely an extract of what feels the interesting part, but maybe some more obscure part of the `Makefile` does have an effect here. To be investigated ...